# Items Greyed Out in Xcode After Copying Between Storyboards

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard

I have two storyboards and copied and pasted a view from one to the other. It still works normally however all of the items are greyed out like it is in the wrong size configuration. You can see my picture below showing the problem. I have the width and height set to exactly the same in both storyboards but Xcode is acting like it is in the wrong configuration to edit. (Yes, I've tried changing the configuration but all of them still present greyed out items).

[image: Greyed out Xcode issues]

Comment: It looks like they are either hidden, or disabled for this trait collection configuration.

Comment: I have gone through and made sure that they are not hidden or disabled on the individual item and cannot find any evidence of such.

Comment: Including for different trait collections? http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/